# Android: gridView set not scrollable?

Tags: android, android-gridview

I'm trying to do filter section by gridView. In a wide screen it's fine. But when it's small screen is not working correctly. (One view is two or three times, some is dissapearing) It's because gridView item's shrinking and scroll is appearing. So i trying to remove gridView scroll.

My activity is.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:scrollbars="vertical">
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">


    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark"
        app:titleTextColor="@android:color/white"
        app:contentInsetStartWithNavigation="0dp">
    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">


        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="11"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dp">

        <TextView
            android:text="Price"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="start|bottom"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/seekbar_value"
            android:text="Any"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center|bottom"
            android:textStyle="bold"/>


        <org.florescu.android.rangeseekbar.RangeSeekBar
            android:id="@+id/range_seekbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:showLabels="false"
            app:valuesAboveThumbs="false"
            app:barHeight="5dp"
            app:alwaysActive="true"
            app:thumbDisabled="@drawable/seekbar_button"
            app:textAboveThumbsColor="@color/colorPrimary"
            app:defaultColor="@color/colorPrimary"
            app:activeColor="@color/colorButton" />

        <TextView
            android:text="Block"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="start|bottom"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"/>

            <GridView
                android:id="@+id/gridViewBlock"
                android:numColumns="auto_fit"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:columnWidth="60dp"
                android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"/>

            <TextView
            android:text="Floor"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="start|bottom"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"/>

           <!--  This Grid View is my problem -->
            **<GridView
                android:id="@+id/gridViewFloor"
                android:numColumns="auto_fit"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:columnWidth="60dp"
                android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"/>**

        </LinearLayout>

        <Button
            android:text="See result"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:background="@color/colorButton"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

And i programmatically adding gridView items:

```
public class FIlterActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Toolbar toolbar;
    private RangeSeekBar seekbar;
    private TextView seekbarValue;
    private GridView gridViewBlock;
    private GridView gridViewFloor;
    private FilterButtonAdapter filterBlockAdapter;
    private FilterButtonAdapter filterFloorAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_filter);
        toolbar = (Toolbar)findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        toolbar.setTitle(getString(R.string.activity_filter));
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        gridViewBlock = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridViewBlock);

        filterBlockAdapter = new FilterButtonAdapter(this, Filter.filter_blocks, Filter.blocks_selected);
        gridViewBlock.setAdapter(filterBlockAdapter);

        gridViewBlock.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long id) {

                final TextView textView = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.filter_button);
                String value = textView.getText().toString();
                boolean contain = false;

                for(int i = 0; i < Filter.blocks_selected.size(); i++){
                    if(value.equals(Filter.blocks_selected.get(i).toString())) {
                        view.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.button_disabled);
                        Filter.blocks_selected.remove(i);
                        if(Filter.blocks_selected.size() == 0){
                            Filter.blocks_selected.add(Filter.filter_blocks[0]);
                            adapterView.getChildAt(0).setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.button_enabled);
                        }
                        contain = true;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                if(!contain){
                    if(value.equals("Any")){
                        Filter.blocks_selected.clear();
                        Filter.blocks_selected.add(Filter.filter_blocks[0]);
                        for(int i = 1; i < Filter.filter_blocks.length; i++){
                            adapterView.getChildAt(i).setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.button_disabled);
                        }
                    }
                    else{
                        for(int i = 0; i < Filter.blocks_selected.size(); i++){
                            if(Filter.blocks_selected.get(i).toString().equals("Any")){
                                adapterView.getChildAt(0).setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.button_disabled);
                                Filter.blocks_selected.remove(i);
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    view.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.button_enabled);
                    Filter.blocks_selected.add(value);}
                filterBlockAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });

        gridViewFloor = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridViewFloor);
        filterFloorAdapter = new FilterButtonAdapter(this, Filter.filter_floors, Filter.floor_selected);
        gridViewFloor.setAdapter(filterFloorAdapter);


        gridViewFloor.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long id) {


                final TextView textView = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.filter_button);
                String value = textView.getText().toString();
                boolean contain = false;

                for(int i = 0; i < Filter.floor_selected.size(); i++){
                    if(value.equals(Filter.floor_selected.get(i).toString())) {
                        view.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.button_disabled);
                        Filter.floor_selected.remove(i);
                        if(Filter.floor_selected.size() == 0){
                            Filter.floor_selected.add(Filter.filter_floors[0]);
                            adapterView.getChildAt(0).setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.button_enabled);
                        }
                        contain = true;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                if(!contain){
                    if(value.equals("Any")){
                        Filter.floor_selected.clear();
                        Filter.floor_selected.add(Filter.filter_floors[0]);
                        for(int i = 1; i < Filter.filter_floors.length; i++){
                            adapterView.getChildAt(i).setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.button_disabled);
                        }
                    }
                    else{
                        for(int i = 0; i < Filter.floor_selected.size(); i++){
                            if(Filter.floor_selected.get(i).toString().equals("Any")){
                                adapterView.getChildAt(0).setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.button_disabled);
                                Filter.floor_selected.remove(i);
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    view.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.button_enabled);
                    Filter.floor_selected.add(value);}
                filterFloorAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });



        seekbar = (RangeSeekBar)findViewById(R.id.range_seekbar);
        seekbarValue = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.seekbar_value);

        seekbar.setOnRangeSeekBarChangeListener(new RangeSeekBar.OnRangeSeekBarChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onRangeSeekBarValuesChanged(RangeSeekBar bar, Object minValue, Object maxValue) {
                if(String.valueOf(bar.getAbsoluteMaxValue()).equals(maxValue.toString())){

                    if(String.valueOf(bar.getAbsoluteMinValue()).equals(minValue.toString()))
                        seekbarValue.setText("Бүх");
                    else {
                        seekbarValue.setText(minValue.toString() + " $ - +");
                    }
                } else if(String.valueOf(bar.getAbsoluteMinValue()).equals(minValue.toString())){
                    seekbarValue.setText(maxValue.toString() + " $ - -");
                } else{
                    seekbarValue.setText(minValue.toString() + " $ - " + maxValue.toString() + " $");
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

And Filter Button Adapter

```
public class FilterButtonAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private Context context;
    private final String[] filterValues;
    private List<String> checkedFilterValues = new ArrayList<String>();


    public FilterButtonAdapter(Context context, String[] filterValues, List<String> checkedFilterValues){
        this.context = context;
        this.filterValues = filterValues;
        this.checkedFilterValues = checkedFilterValues;
    }
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return filterValues.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int i) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int i) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        View gridView;
        if(convertView == null){

            gridView = new View(context);
            gridView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_button, null);

            final TextView textView = (TextView)gridView.findViewById(R.id.filter_button);
            textView.setText(filterValues[position]);

            boolean contain = false;
            for(int i = 0; i < Filter.blocks_selected.size(); i++){
                if(filterValues[position].equals(checkedFilterValues.get(i)))
                {
                    gridView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.button_enabled);
                    contain = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if(!contain){
                gridView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.button_disabled);
            }
        } else gridView = (View)convertView;
        return gridView;
    }
}
```

Filter class:

```
public class Filter {

    public static String price = "any";
    public static long priceMax = 0;
    public static long priceMin = 0;
    public static final String[] filter_blocks = new String[]{
            "any", "A", "B", "C"
    };
    public static final String[] filter_floors = new String[]{
            "any", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6",
            "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12+"
    };

    public static List<String> blocks_selected = new ArrayList<String>(){{
        add("any");
    }
    };

    public static List<String> floor_selected = new ArrayList<String>(){{
        add("any");
    }
    };

    public static int floor = 10;

}
```

My android studio emulator is 2.7 QVGA API 25

Comment: Make `gridView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false)`

Comment: requiring Lollilop API

Comment: my project minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 26

Comment: https://ibb.co/cbnDfF

Comment: it's appearing wrong order. And dissapearing

Comment: What is your exact problem?

Comment: https://ibb.co/cbnDfF

Comment: in this image 3 and 7 seven is wrong order

Comment: and some of it's dissapeared

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `GridView` inside `ScrollView`, because both has scrolling functionality and due to this it will not work properly.

Use `NestedScrollView` instead of `ScrollView`.

> `NestedScrollView` is just like `ScrollView`, but it supports acting
>   as both a `nested` scrolling `parent` and `child` on both new and old
>   versions of Android. Nested scrolling is enabled by default.

See [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/NestedScrollView.html).

**Update your layout structure as below:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/layout_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark"
            app:titleTextColor="@android:color/white"
            app:contentInsetStartWithNavigation="0dp">
        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:id="@+id/layout_scorll"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="20dp">

                <TextView
                    android:text="Price"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="start|bottom"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
                    android:layout_marginTop="20dp" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/seekbar_value"
                    android:text="Any"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center|bottom"
                    android:textStyle="bold"/>

               <org.florescu.android.rangeseekbar.RangeSeekBar
                    android:id="@+id/range_seekbar"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    app:showLabels="false"
                    app:valuesAboveThumbs="false"
                    app:barHeight="5dp"
                    app:alwaysActive="true"
                    app:thumbDisabled="@drawable/seekbar_button"
                    app:textAboveThumbsColor="@color/colorPrimary"
                    app:defaultColor="@color/colorPrimary"
                    app:activeColor="@color/colorButton" />

                <TextView
                    android:text="Block"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="start|bottom"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
                    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"/>

                <GridView
                    android:id="@+id/gridViewBlock"
                    android:numColumns="auto_fit"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:columnWidth="60dp"
                    android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false"/>

                <TextView
                    android:text="Floor"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="start|bottom"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
                    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"/>

                <!--  This Grid View is my problem -->
                <GridView
                    android:id="@+id/gridViewFloor"
                    android:numColumns="auto_fit"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:columnWidth="60dp"
                    android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false"/>

            </LinearLayout>

            <Button
                android:text="See result"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:background="@color/colorAccent"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

        </RelativeLayout>
    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView> is it? not even scrolling

Comment: YES.  Try adding attribute `android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false"` to your two `GridView`.

Comment: activity is not scrolling?

Comment: Thanks. But i want to remove gridView Scroll. Add activity scroll?

Comment: Then you can give fixed height to your GridView using layout_weight or layout_height. Add weightSum to container LinearLayout.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this**

```
ViewCompat.setNestedScrollingEnabled(gridView, true);
```